# C - Check_expect_i and segmentation fault (core dumped)

Tags: c, sum

I tried to do a short a program in **C** in order to create functions to calculate a sum of cube of numbers (like 2*2*2 for example) but I got this message when I tried to launch the program:

> "segmentation default (core dumped)"
>
> sum_even_cubes.c, line 14: check passed sum_even_cubes.c, line 15:
>   check passed sum_even_cubes.c, line 16: check passed sum_even_cubes.c,
>   line 17: check passed sum_even_cubes.c, line 18: check passed
>
> sum_even_cubes.c, line 56: check passed sum_even_cubes.c, line 57:
>   check passed Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Below my program in **C** : (the bug occurs probably at the function sum_even_cubes_rec() )

```
#include "base.h"

int sum_even_cubes(int n);

void sum_even_cubes_test(void) {
// a)

check_expect_i(sum_even_cubes(0), 0);
check_expect_i(sum_even_cubes(1), 0);
check_expect_i(sum_even_cubes(2), 8);
check_expect_i(sum_even_cubes(3), 8);
check_expect_i(sum_even_cubes(4), 72);
}
int sum_even_cubes(int n) {
  // b)

 int sum_even_cubes = 0 ;

if(n%2==0){
    for(int i=0 ; i<=n ; i+=2){
        sum_even_cubes = ( sum_even_cubes + ( i*i*i ) );
    }

    return sum_even_cubes;
   }

if(n%2!=0){

    for(int i=0 ; i<=(n-1) ; i+=2){
        sum_even_cubes = ( sum_even_cubes + ( i*i*i ) );
    }

    return sum_even_cubes;

}

return 404;
}
int sum_even_cubes_rec(int n);

void sum_even_cubes_rec_test(void) {
// a)

check_expect_i(sum_even_cubes_rec(0), 0);
check_expect_i(sum_even_cubes_rec(1), 0);
check_expect_i(sum_even_cubes_rec(2), 8);
check_expect_i(sum_even_cubes_rec(3), 8);
check_expect_i(sum_even_cubes_rec(4), 72);} 

   int sum_even_cubes_rec(int n) {
    // c)



if(n%2==0){

    if(n==0){return 0;}

    if(n!=0){return ( sum_even_cubes_rec(n) + sum_even_cubes_rec((n-2))         )         ;}

}

if(n%2!=0){

    if(n==1){return 0;}

    if(n!=1){return ( sum_even_cubes_rec((n-1)) + sum_even_cubes_rec((n-3)) ) ;}

}

return 404;
   }
   int sum_even_cubes_rec2(int n, int acc);

   void sum_even_cubes_rec2_test(void) {
// a)
check_expect_i(sum_even_cubes_rec2(0,0), 0);
check_expect_i(sum_even_cubes_rec2(1,0), 0);
check_expect_i(sum_even_cubes_rec2(2,0), 8);
check_expect_i(sum_even_cubes_rec2(3,0), 8);
check_expect_i(sum_even_cubes_rec2(4,0), 72);
  }

  int sum_even_cubes_rec2(int n, int acc) {
// d)

if(n%2==0){

    if(n==0){return acc;}

    if(n!=0){return ( sum_even_cubes_rec2(n-2, acc + n*n*n) );}

}

if(n%2!=0){
    if(n==1){return acc;}

    if(n!=1){return ( sum_even_cubes_rec2(n-2, acc + (n-1)*(n-1)*(n-1)) )        ;}

}

return 404;
    }


int main(void) {
sum_even_cubes_test();
printf("\n");
sum_even_cubes_rec_test();
printf("\n");
sum_even_cubes_rec2_test();
    }
```

Sorry for the source code, I didn't get how to highlight it completely as **C** programming source code.

Comment: What does this have to do with the Expect scripting tool?

Comment: `sum_even_cubes_rec(n)` in `sum_even_cubes_rec(n)`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what the objective is of this program, but a really easy way to write successful programs is to work with a solid foundation and build upon it.

Below is a program that iteratively calculates the cube of a number. You could also simply return the number multiplied by itself 3 times or `(x*x*x)`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int simpleCube(int x){
    return (x*x*x);
}

int iterativeCube(int x, int n){
    int i, total = 1;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++){
        total *= x;
    }
    return total;
}

int main(){
    printf("2 Cubed is %d\n", iterativeCube(2, 3));
    return 0;
}
```

Here is a program that calculates the cube of a number using `math.h`'s `pow()` function.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(){
    int base = 2, exponent = 3, result;
    result = pow(base, exponent);
    printf("%d^%d = %d\n", base, exponent, result);
    return 0;
}
```

If you want to sum up all of the cubes from 1 to n:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(){
    int i, n = 10, result, totalEven = 0, totalOdd = 0;
    for (i = 1; i < n; i++){
        if (i % 2 == 0){
            /* The number is even */
            result = pow(i, 3);
            totalEven += result;
        } else {
            /* The number is odd */
            result = pow(i, 3);
            totalOdd += result;
        }
    }
    printf("The sum of all even cubes from 1 to %d is %d.\n", n, totalEven);
    printf("The sum of all odd cubes from 1 to %d is %d.\n", n, totalOdd);
    printf("The sum of all cubes from 1 to %d is %d.\n", n, totalEven+totalOdd);
    return 0;
}
```